# org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.xptraining.model.Representative

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

Error

```
  Caused by: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.xptraining.model.Representative
```

cart controller class

```
    @POST
    @Path(XpConstants.PLACE_ORDER)
    @Consumes("application/json")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public Status placeOrder1(Carts carts) {

        Representative r2 = carts.getRepresentative();
        List<Sku> sList = carts.getListSku();
        CartsOrderDto cartOrderDto = new CartsOrderDto();
        Sku s = new Sku();
        try {
            cartOrderDto.setCartId(carts.getCartId());
            cartOrderDto.setTotalBill(carts.getPrize());
            cartOrderDto.setProductList(carts.getListSku());
            cartOrderDto.setRepresentative(carts.getRepresentative());

            Carts c = new Carts();
            c.setCartId(carts.getCartId());
            cartServices.deleteCart(carts.getCartId());
            for (Sku sku : sList) {
                s.setPrize(sku.getPrize());
                s.setProduct(sku.getProduct());
                s.setQuanity(sku.getQuanity());
                s.setSize(sku.getSize());
                s.setSkuId(sku.getSkuId());
                s.setSkuName(sku.getSkuName());
                s.setUnitName(sku.getUnitName());
                skuServices.addSku(s);
            }
            Orders orders = new Orders();
            orders.setCurrentDate(Utilities.getTodaysDate());
            orders.setStatus("Active");
            orders.setRepresentative(r2);
            orders.setListSku(sList);

            representativeServices.addRepresentative(r2);
            orderServices.saveOrders(orders);

            logger.info("Record saved in order and deleted from cart sucessfully");
            return new Status(1, XpConstants.RECORD_SAVED);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(XpConstants.ERROR_OCCURED, e);

        }

        return new Status(1, XpConstants.PLACED_WRONG_ID);

    }
```

Entity classes :

Cart.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "carts")
public class Carts {
    @Id
    @Column(name = CARTS_ID)
    private long cartId;

    @Column(name = PRIZE)
    private int prize;


    @ElementCollection(targetClass=Product.class)
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL , fetch=FetchType.EAGER )
    @JoinTable(
            name = "CARTS_SKU",
            joinColumns = {  @JoinColumn(name = CARTS_ID) },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = SKU_ID) }
    )
    private List<Sku> listSku;


    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL ,fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name=REPRESENTATIVE_ID)
    private Representative representative;

}
```

Orders.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = Orders.TABLE_NAME)
public class Orders {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = Order.ORDER_ID)
    private long ordersId;

    @Column(name = CURRENT_DATE)
    private Date currentDate;

    @Column(name = STATUS)
    private String status;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = REPRESENTATIVE_ID)
    private Representative representative;

    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    @ElementCollection(targetClass = Product.class)
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "ORDERS_SKU",
    joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = ORDER_ID) },
    inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = SKU_ID) })
    private List<Sku> listSku;
}
```

Representative.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = Representative.TABLE_NAME)
public class Representative implements java.io.Serializable {   
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = REPRESENTATIVE_ID)
    private long representativeId;

    @Column(name = FIRST_NAME)
    private String representativeFirstName;

    @Column(name = LAST_NAME)
    private String representativeLastName;

    @Column(name = EMAIL)
    private String representativeEmail;

    @Column(name = PASSWORD)
    private String representativePassword;

    @Column(name = EMPID)
    private int representativeEmpId;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToOne(mappedBy="representative", cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST , fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private Orders orders;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToOne(mappedBy="representative", cascade=CascadeType.ALL , fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private Carts carts;
}
```

sku.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = Sku.TABLE_NAME)
public class Sku implements java.io.Serializable  {

    @Id
    @Column(name = SKU_ID)
    private long skuId;

    @Column(name = SKU_NAME)
    private String skuName;

    @Column(name = UNIT_NAME)
    private String unitName;

    @Column(name = SIZE)
    private String size;

    @Column(name = PRIZE)
    private int prize;

    @Column(name = QUANTITY)
    private int quanity;


    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER , cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = PRODUCT_ID , nullable = false)
    private Product product;

}
```

Product.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = Product.TABLE_NAME)
public class Product implements java.io.Serializable  {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = PRODUCT_ID)
    private long productId;

    @Column(name = PRODUCT_NAME )
    private String productName;

    @Column(name = SPECIALITY_ID)
    private int specialtyId;

    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    @ElementCollection(targetClass=Product.class)
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="product" , cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Sku> listSkuOrders = new ArrayList<Sku>();
}
```

Also there are two extra tables which is created by @JoinTable annotation 
i e 1.carts_sku 2.orders_sku

service impl method for cart:

```
/**
 * Delete Cart
 * 
 * @param id
 *            cart id
 * @throws Exception
 */
@Override
@Transactional
public void deleteCart(long id) throws Exception {

    cartsRepository.delete(id);
}
```

service impl method for order:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public Orders saveOrders(Orders orders) {
    return ordersRepository.save(orders);
}
```

When i am deleting cart record by cart id it is deleted bt it can not be saved to the order it showing following error

```
    org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: detached entity passed to persist: com.xptraining.model.Representative; nested exception is org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.xptraining.model.Representative

Caused by: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.xptraining.model.Representative
```

Comment: can you share you service implementation?

Comment: hii i m updated that 2 methods in question Thanks u ..!!!

Comment: please share the Product code aswell

Comment: Hello , i updated Product.java  in question Thank You...!!!

Comment: I suppose you are using spring jpa  repository ?

Comment: yes i used jpa repository

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141887/discussion-between-harshad-kenjale-and-amer-qarabsa).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your `carts` in `placeOrder1()` is detached because it comes as a JSON request. Therefore `carts.representative` is also detached. You may need attach  `carts.representative` to the session by doing for example `session.merge()` or `entityManager.merge()` (probably through a service class which has access to the `session`) See https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Session.html for other options for re-attaching.

The attachment must be done before you try to save `carts.representative` as part of `Order`

Comment: This is my Service impl method , u r trying to say i have to attach Representative object before deleting the whole cart details    ...??? 
 @Transactional
 public void deleteCart(long id) throws Exception {
  cartsRepository.delete(id);
 }

Comment: I do not know your complete setup, but for testing purpose you can try adding field `@PersistenceContext   private EntityManager entityManager;` in the controller. If spring successfully populates it, you can then call `entityManager.merge()` on the `carts.representative` (I assume the Representative exists and is not deleted). Tell me how it goes.

Comment: its throwing null value let me show u what i did i i'll update it in question.

Comment: I think it is null because it is not inside a `@Transactional` context. Try adding the field in the `RepresentativeService` instead. In there, create a new method called `attach(Representative rep)` which then calls   `entityManager.merge(rep)`. I assume `RepresentativeService` is transactional.

Comment: RepresentativeService  :>>                                                                    public Representative attach(Representative rep);                          RepresentativeServiceImpl   :>>                                                                                               
 @Transactional
 public Representative attach(Representative rep) {
  entityManager.merge(rep);
  return rep;
 }

Comment: When i m going to add sku list at that time i get the following error Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`training`.`orders_sku`, CONSTRAINT `FKfg9x7j6ciycdnf9uiilarrx5s` FOREIGN KEY (`sku_id`) REFERENCES `sku` (`sku_id`))

Comment: That is because you are sending in an id of the sk in your json request. Do you want to create a new or use existing? If you want to create new you must not send ID of sku and look at cascade type on sku. In any case check this out: https://vladmihalcea.com/2015/03/05/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-and-hibernate-cascade-types/.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142068/discussion-between-harshad-kenjale-and-qtips).

Comment: Great! Nice to hear :)

Comment: hello you there ??

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is you are trying to persist a detached  object, In your Cars class you have

```
  @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL ,fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name=REPRESENTATIVE_ID)
private Representative representative;
```

since the cascade type is all , all the operations will be cascaded including the remove.

```
 cartServices.deleteCart(carts.getCartId());
```

when deleting the cart the representative will be detached ( since you are still holding a reference to it)

when you add it to the order and save the issue will occur.

To solve the issue you either need to reattach the object or change the cascade type to persist

Comment: Hello , i changed cascate type as  cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST
  but still it showing same error .

Comment: you removed it inside the charts?

Answer (score 1):

Change `CascadeType.ALL` to `CascadeType.MERGE`

`CascadeType.ALL` tries to remove the reference and re-inserts with a new Id, which results in error, But `CascadeType.MERGE` tries to use the same reference and persists the reference, then updates the new data if any.